# bug in codedeploy afterinstall hook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, composer-php, symfony, aws-code-deploy

We have autoscaling set up for our symfony3 application. We are using aws codedeploy to deploy to autoscaling instances.

My appspec.yml file

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /usr/share/nginx/<some_dir>
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: post_deploy.sh
      timeout: 180
      runas: ubuntu
```

post_deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
doc_root=/usr/share/nginx/<some_dir>
current_dir=$PWD
cd $doc_root
sudo -E composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
cd $current_dir
```

and also exported environment variables for parameters.yml file

when we deploy revision, codedeploy succeed in deployment. But when i access my app through browser, nginx error log says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException' with message 'You have requested a non-existent parameter "database.host". Did you mean one of these: "database_host", "database_port"?
```

Strange thing is that when i run post_deploy.sh script manually by logging in to my server it executes well and no error afterwards.
I don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

codedeploy doesn't preserve env var in spite of `-E` option.
So i pass the env var in command itself, like this

```
sudo SYMFONY_ENV=$SYMFONY_ENV SYMFONY__DATABASE__NAME=$SYMFONY__DATABASE__NAME SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER=$SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER SYMFONY__DATABASE__HOST=$SYMFONY__DATABASE__HOST SYMFONY__DATABASE__PORT=$SYMFONY__DATABASE__PORT SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD=$SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD COMPOSER_HOME=$COMPOSER_HOME composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change database.host to database_host. that what's indicated in the message.

Comment: thats because sudo doesn't preserve env var, thats why `-E`
if you run `sudo -E composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader` it will succeed and if you run this command without `-E` option it will throw mentioned exceptionerror